# Set value for all checkboxes with coffescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How me change value of others checkboxes 'checked' to 'false', if current checkbox is checked true?

I am using for checkboxes library jquery-labelauty

**projects/_responses.html.erb**

```
<% @project.responses.each do |response| %>   
    ..........................................
    <div class="controls">
     <%= check_box_tag '', true, false, { class: "control__check" } %>  
    </div>
    ..............................................
  <% end %>
```

**projects.js.coffeescript**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('#project_skill_list').tagit 
    allowSpaces:true,
    tagLimit: 15

  $('.control__check').labelauty
    checked_label: "Cancel",
    unchecked_label: "Select",
    force_random_id: true

  $('.control__check labelauty').change ->
    checkboxes = $(this).siblings()
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
      checkboxes.prop('checked', false)
```

If I click one checkbox, nothing happens. How me fix issue?

Comment: try this by "click" event instead of "change"

Comment: Are these really radio buttons?